# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - GNOME Flashback Install with Search Error

Tags: gnome, search

I have just installed GNOME Flashback from Ubuntu Software Centre and have also added the Search Tool within a panel.

Unfortunately when I click on the magnify glass I receive the error:

**Could not launch 'gnome-search-tool' - Failed to execute child process "gnome-search-tool" (No such file or directory)**

I have no idea what this means and how to fix it.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution just in case someone has the same issue, simply run the command:

**sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool**

Found this soliution [here](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/precise/universe/g/gnome-search-tool/install/index.html)